# HTML anchor tag is not redirecting

Tags: html, css, anchor

I am having trouble in using the anchor tag(in this instance).

```html
 for($i=0;$i<$numrows;$i++)
echo "
<div class='singleItem'> 
  <img src= $arr3[$i] class='itemImage'> 
  <div class='itemName'> $arr1[$i] </div> 
  <div class='itemPrice'><br> Php$arr2[$i] 
      <div class='orderButtonDiv'>
          <a href='menu_burger.php?itemid=$arr4[$i]'>ORDER</a>
      </div> 
  </div>
</div> "
```

As you may notice i am creating multiple instance of *singleItem* and upon finishing,it seems i am not able to click the anchor tag. As if maybe it got behind by something. I know the link works since upon inspecting elements in chrome shows correct links.

here is the css

```css
.itemImage{
  width :80%;
  height: 80%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: left;
  padding-top:4%;
  padding-left: 2%;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.itemName{
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Akzidenz-Grotesk BQ",sans-serif;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-top: 4%;
  z-index -1;
}

.itemPrice{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Akzidenz-Grotesk BQ",sans-serif;
  font-size: 110%;
  margin-left: 41%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25%;
  z-index -1;
}

.singleItem{
  width: 48%;
  background-color: #e0dede;
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.rowItem{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.listItems{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 75%;
  /* margin-top: 130px ; */
}

.orderButtonDiv{
  display: inline;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  right: -50%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  z-index 3;
}

.orderButtonDiv a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Akzidenz-Grotesk BQ",sans-serif;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;

}
```

I tried almost everything by making the whole singleItem,orderButtonDiv class clickable by using Jquery and still to no success.

if someone could offer some help it would be great, and appreciated Thank you

Comment: Please provide a _proper_ [mcve] for cases like this. Your code snippet above, when run, currently shows _nothing at all_.

Answer (score 2):

To redirect to an anchor, this anchor must have an `id` and your url `#yourid`

```
<a href="#myId">Link to My ID</a>
```

this link redirect to this div :

```
<div id="myId">My ID</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it has something to do with the `z-index: -1;` on the `div`with the `singleItem` class - when this is removed the anchor tag is clickable - hope that helps

Comment: Got it working by removing z-indexes thank you ! , but i dont understand because there were no items _above_ it. why does that disable it?

Comment: No worries! I think the z-index is forcing the <a> tag to the very back "layer" due to the div order

Answer (score 2):

There is error in writing `z-index` please check it should be `z-index:1` you have missed the (:) and instead fo giving `z-index:-1;` set the `z-index:1;` and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <a href='menu_burger.php?itemid=$arr4[$i]'>ORDER</a>
```

pls change into

```
      <a href="menu_burger.php?itemid=<?php echo $arr4['$i']?>"> ORDER </a>
```

hope this will b correct if not sorry try it